# Get whole line containing last occurrence of value in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

I have a long table (50k lines and 15 columns) where different users report a status using a google-form (the table is always chronologically sorted), and I want to obtain the last report of each user. I have managed to do it, but it takes too long to reload, I know that the formulas I use are too heavy for the spreadsheet, but I can't find any better way to do it.

To simplify the scenery, the case can be applied to the following input and desired output:

Input:

```
|      Timestamp      | User |  Status  |
|:-------------------:|:----:|:--------:|
| 2019-01-03 10:00:30 |   A  | Started  |
| 2019-01-03 10:01:41 |   B  | Started  |
| 2019-01-03 10:02:00 |   B  | Finished |
| 2019-01-03 10:02:14 |   C  | Started  |
| 2019-01-03 10:03:22 |   A  | Failed   |
| 2019-01-03 10:00:04 |   C  | Finished |
```

Output:

```
|      Timestamp      | User |  Status  |
|:-------------------:|:----:|:--------:|
| 2019-01-03 10:02:00 |   B  | Finished |
| 2019-01-03 10:03:22 |   A  | Failed   |
| 2019-01-03 10:00:04 |   C  | Finished |
```

I managed to do it combining a pivot table with ***user*** as row and ***max(Timestamp)*** as value and then feed that information to a formula (*maybe INDEX and MATCH would have been a better approach*):

```
OFFSET('Sheet1'!$A$1,ArrayFormula(max(if('Sheet1'!$B:$B=$A3, Row('Sheet1'!$B:$B))))-1,column()-1)
```

I also tried with the following approach for each unique result.

```
|      Unique users      |                                     Query                                     |
|:----------------------:|:-----------------------------------------------------------------------------:|
| =UNIQUE('Sheet1'!$A:$A) | =QUERY('Sheet1'!$A:$C, "SELECT A, C WHERE B='"&B2&"' ORDER BY A DESC LIMIT 1",0) |
```

From what I have read, combining ARRAYFORMULA and QUERY might improve the performance, but I have not been able to pull it off.

Comment: Array formulas will take too long with that many cells. If you are handy with google apps script you can write a script that does this for you once, and then another that executes on each new form submission if you want a 'live' version.

Comment: This is the best approach when it comes to fluency as it does not use any formula, I am afraid that it's what I will have to do. For the moment I am going to use **JPV**'s answer and I'll do an GAP when I have some spare time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Timestamp in col A, User in Col B and Status in col C try

```
=Arrayformula(iferror(vlookup(unique (B2:B), sort({B2:B, A2:C}, 2, 0), {2, 3, 4}, 0)))
```

Comment: Thank you. It stills takes its toll on the sheet, but it's definitively more fluid.